# Error when store char in int array

Tags: c

I have written Transposition Cipher by C and confuse about output of this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

main()
{
char plain[]="Ibrahimovic called them babies in Champions League";
int row,col,key,i=0;

printf("key length: ");
scanf("%d%*c",&key);

int enc[(int) (ceil(strlen(plain)/key))][key];

for(row=0; row<(int) (ceil( (double) strlen(plain)/key)); ++row)
{
    for(col=0; col<key; ++col)
    {
        if(i==strlen(plain))
            enc[row][col]='^';  
        else if(i>strlen(plain))
            enc[row][col]='%';
        else
            enc[row][col]=plain[i];
        printf(" %c |",enc[row][col]);
        ++i;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

putchar('"');
for(col=0; col<key ; ++col)
    for(row=0; row<(int) (ceil((double) strlen(plain)/key)) ; ++row)
            printf("%c",enc[row][col]);
puts("\"\n");
}
```

This is output when key=8.

```
 I | b | r | a | h | i | m | o |
 v | i | c |   | c | a | l | l |
 e | d |   | t | h | e | m |   |
 b | a | b | i | e | s |   | i |
 n |   | C | h | a | m | p | i |
 o | n | s |   | L | e | a | g |
 u | e | ^ | % | % | % | % | % |

"Ivebnoubida nerc bCs^a tih %hcheaL%iaesme%mlm pa�ol iig%"
```

So output of printf function in the loop indicate that all elements in `enc` array is correct. But when I printf it outside the loop, one of elements is wrong.

If I change format of printf function outside loop to print integer value, it indicate that the wrong element have value -1.

```
"73 118 101 98 110 111 117 98 105 100 97 32 110 101 114 99 32 98 67 115 94 97 32 116 105 104 32 37 104 99 104 101 97 76 37 105 97 101 115 109 101 37 109 108 109 32 112 97 **-1** 111 108 32 105 105 103 37 "
```

So what problem in my code? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
int enc[(int) (ceil(strlen(plain)/key))][key];
```

This line has an integer division, I assume you want a floating point one and missed the cast.

Comment: yeah, I corrected that mistake and result from output is right. Thanks